# Apache pig program

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, bigdata

Need help to write pig script for counting the no:of words in a

file containing the below text

```
What|is|Hadoop
History|of|Hadoop
How|Hadoop|name|was|given
Problems|with|Traditional|Large-Scale|Systems|and|Need|for|Hadoop
Understanding|Hadoop|Architecture
Fundamental|of|HDFS|(Blocks,|Name|Node,|Data|Node,|Secondary|Name|Node)
Rack|Awareness
Read/Write|from|HDFS
HDFS|Federation|and|High|Availability
```

Answer (score 0):

Load the data into a chararray.Replace the '|' with space i.e. ' ' and Tokenize the line which will give you the words and then group and count the words

```
A = LOAD '/user/hadoop/data.txt' AS (line:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(REPLACE(line,'\\|',' ')));
C = GROUP B BY $0;
D = FOREACH C GENERATE group, COUNT(B);
DUMP D;
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: From the above code the output I am getting single letters. I would like to display words and then count. output looks like this:  (W)
(h)
(a)
(t)
(|)
(i)
(s)
(|)
(H)
(a)
(d)
(o)
(o)
(p)  ... I would like to display the output in the following way(what),(hadoop)..could u pls help